# Can you run a VPN in a VM whilst the host OS doesn't?

Tags: vmware, vpn, virtualization, openvpn

Simple question I guess: am I able to have a Win7 VM use a VPN whilst my host OS (most probably Win7 as well) isn't?

Essentially, when I want to use an encrypted VPN connection I want to be able to load up my VM whilst still maintaining regular browsing through my host OS?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: This is my primary reason for using VMs; so I don't have to install awful software like CheckPoint

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works perfectly fine and it is what I do (VMWare Workstation) on many occasions, especially when doing a contract job with a company where I do not want all their software on my machine (many insist on having their VPN, AV and more!)

Comment: Seconded - I run Windows XP in Virtualbox on a laptop running Fedora 14 and use OpenVPN to connect back into work. This configuration lets me support some of the Windows-based apps we use.